# First-class patterns in Erlang?

Tags: macros, erlang, language-features, first-class

Are there any support for *[first-class patterns](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/classic/message5169.html)* in Erlang?

```
f(SomeMagicPattern) ->
  receive
    SomeMagicPattern -> ok
  end.
```

If the answer is no (support), do  you know any other approach for achieving this? For example, using macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Erlang doesn't have first-class patterns out of the box.
There are two ways of implementing this:

1. Macros. Widely used, for example in testing tools like EUnit and PropEr. Say, EUnit has an ?assertMatch macro, which is in fact an example of first-class patterns:

   ?assertMatch({ok, _}, Result)
2. Parse transforms. Harder to write, but potentially more powerful, since using them you can access Erlang abstract code and rewrite it completely, in any way you desire. There's a nice link to a series of tutorials on parse transforms here: [Is there a good, complete tutorial on Erlang parse transforms available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416192/is-there-a-good-complete-tutorial-on-erlang-parse-transforms-available)

Comment: That Erlang doesn't have first-class patterns is the reason why we have the *match patterns* in `ETS` and in the tracing. Not elegant but necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As demeshchuk points out this is not the case.

There is however a proposal to add something similar to the language:

http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0029.html

Whether or not this is a good idea is a completely different question...